# Not able to push code from Vs Code interface to gitlab. Git: git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive)

Tags: angular, git, gitlab

I'm using mac. My vs code is sorta connected to the gitlab. I can commit the code using VS code interface but not able to push the code to the repo; however, i can push the code using terminal(git push). Not sure how i can make my Vs code push the code without having to open terminal and do git push.

Every time i push the code from vs interface i get the error "Git: git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey, keyboard-interactive)."
Let me know if anyone knows about this, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`git@gitlab.com` means SSH URL

Try and check what `ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com` returns when done in the Terminal of VSCode itself.

Check [this thread](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/git-git-gitlab-com-permission-denied-publickey-with-vsc/33108) which includes assuming your private SSH key is passphrase-protected):

> It is most likely because your SSH key wasn’t “unlocked”.
>
> On Mac after creating an SSH key you can add it to the keychain with:
>
> ```
> ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/[your-private-key]
> ```
>
> And in `~/.ssh/config` you add:
>
> ```yaml
> Host *
>  UseKeychain yes
>  AddKeysToAgent yes
>  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/[your-private-key]
> ```
>
> So it knows where to look, and this will also make it so you don’t need to enter the passphrase each time, and thus VSCode is allowed to use they key, cause it’s unlocked not just when you’re pushing through CLI

Comment: I did your steps and again same thing came in while pushing from vs code. 

When i did ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com, it returns this (i've copied only last 5 lines) 

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).

if needed i can copy all the lines and show.

Comment: @HemantaSharma in the terminal, in the root folder of your repository, does a `git remote -v` return an SSH URL starting with `git@gitlab.com:...`? Or an HTTPS URL starting with `https://gitlab.com`?

Comment: first ssh-add command did the trick for me on my machine, thank you so much!! 

Comment: @JohnFox Great! I am glad that was helpful.